# Number conversion problem using built in method in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

Suppose if the value is >.5 it will return 1 but if it's<.5 it'll return 0. Is there any built in method in python to do this?I want to use this in machine learning. If possible please give me a sample

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` has a round function that will round to nearest floating point, which you could use.  Or just make your own.  Something like this should work for numbers between [0.0, 1.0] and return integers:

```
>>> def rnd(x):
...     return int(x + 0.5)
... 
>>> rnd(0.4)
0
>>> rnd(0.6)
1
>>> rnd(0.5)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `round()` function in Python.

```
print(round(31.5))  gives 32 and 
print(round(31.4))  gives 31.
```

Does this answer your query?

Comment: Ha!  I forgot that was a native function.  I thought it was in the math module and was scratching my head when it didn't show up.

Comment: @JeffH it happens sometimes. Cheers :)